# Portuguese characters issue in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, html-encode

I have Portuguese string:

```
Sábado das 9 às 15h
```

After I did a webrequest and read the string, the character à is getting converted to something like below:

```
S�bado das 9 �s 15h
```

I did HttpUtility.HtmlDecode. But it did not help. Still the same issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes! **"[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)"**

Comment: You haven't said *how* you read the string.

Comment: @JonSkeet After making a web request, I using xpath to parse html. Language is c#.

Comment: You are parsing the string as though it is utf-8 encoded.  It is not.  Check the http headers for the reported encoding, guess at ISO 8859-1 if unknown.  Which you get from Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)

Comment: @Naveen: You haven't explained how you get the text out of the response though.

Comment: @HansPassant Your guess is right. Encoding is ISO-8859-1.